# How to set environmental variables from code in log4cplus

Tags: c++11, environment-variables

How to set environmental variables from code in log4cplus so that i can use them in configuration files and update it at run time?

Answer (score 0):

This is not log4cplus specific. Use whatever your OS/API provides: `setenv()` or `SetEnvironmentVariable()`.